# How to configure Xunit dotnet core project to initialize from different configuration(Dev, Test, Staging)

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I have a REST api that I want to do Integration tests(not Unit test) using dotnet core 2.0.

The intention is to be able to run these integration tests locally pointing to local dev environment and also with a given Test environment which I am planning to pass on from Teamcity parameters.

I came across this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) describing how to use Configuration in ASP.NET core. I am looking for something similar for xunit projects.

In .NET framework world I managed this by having separate json file for environments and added the [Settings.settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) file to add a variable for test environment and passed on the value of environment before running the tests. However in dotnet core xunit 2.0 projects I am not seeing this Settings.settings file option. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what mechanism/CI/CD pipeline you use for your tests.

That said, you can use environment variables to pass configuration to your xUnit tests. If you use Azure DevOps, for example, environment variables can be supplied via pipeline variables. I've done this successfully with .NET Core 2.1 project in Azure DevOps, so I know this works. I've had issues though with getting this to work in older versions of .NET Core.

For example - in Azure DevOps you would address this as follow

- Create a Build pipeline variable - e.g. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`
- Create Visual Studio Test Task to run your xUnit test
- In your xUnit project, simply use System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")

All the .NET core configuration classes are available via the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` Nuget package

As such, although I haven't tried this, you should be able to use these framework classes directly in your test project to configure parameters for your specific test environments - e.g.

```
new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

The `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` shown above can also be used as an alternative to override default values in appsettings.json

Comment: Thanks Adriaan actually this is what we eventually did. I was trying to use the solution that I had added above but it was only useful for local testing. On CI it was difficult to change where I wanted to run the tests. We solved the problem via ENVIRONMENT variables that I could pass in from Jenkins.

Comment: for a test project, since there's no ```Startup.cs``` or ```Program.cs``` - where do we place this bit of code to make sure it's caught at runtime?

Comment: @JamesGooding: You can put it anywhere; for example, put it in a global/static helper method that can be invoked from any test. If you use xUnit, put it in a Fixture class so that the initialization only occurs once

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with various options on the XUnit project stumbled upon Resources option which is same what we used to refer as Settings.settings in .NET world.

See below screenshot.[image: Resources for a project]

Hope this will help someone in future if they get stuck like me.